# Searching through lists of records with repeating elements

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension, record

I need to make an address book in Erlang. I have done almost everything except for one function that's giving me problems.

My record is:

```
-record(contact, {fname, lname, phone=[], mail=[], city=[], street=[]}).
```

I have to write a function that will search through instances of `contact` and find all with a particular `city` name, and for those instances return `{fname,lname}` tuples. Different contacts can of course have the same cities.

When I needed similar functions for the `mail` and `phone` fields I did it this way:

```
findByPhone(_,[]) -> {error,"not found"};
findByPhone(Phone,[H|T]) ->
  case findPhoneForUser(Phone, H#contact.phone) of
    true -> {H#contact.fname, H#contact.lname};
    false -> findByPhone(Phone, T)
  end.
findPhoneForUser(_,[]) -> false;
findPhoneForUser(Phone, [Phone|_]) -> true;
findPhoneForUser(Phone, [_|T]) -> findPhoneForUser(Phone, T).
```

But both `mail` and `phone` are unique values, so whenever one is found the function is finished. For `city`, a search can yield multiple return values, so it must collect all matches.

How to handle this problem? I thought about list comprehensions something like:

```
{X,Y} || X<-H#contact.fname, Y<-H#contact.lname, City=:=H#contact.city
```

but it will return tuples from single ASCII codes :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension. Assuming your address book is stored in a variable named `AddressBook`, and the city you're matching is stored in a variable named `City`, the following will work:

```
[{C#contact.fname, C#contact.lname} || C <- AddressBook, C#contact.city == City].
```

Also note that you can simplify your `findByPhone` function using the [`lists:keyfind/3` function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3):

```
findByPhone(Phone, AddressBook) ->
    case lists:keyfind(Phone, #contact.phone, AddressBook) of
        #contact{fname=Fname, lname=Lname} -> {Fname, Lname};
        false -> {error, not_found}
    end.
```

This works because records are tuples under the covers. The construct `#contact.phone` used as the second argument to `lists:keyfind/3` provides the element number of the `phone` field of the underlying tuple. In fact, you could write a single non-exported `find` function supporting any unique field in your record with this approach, and then write exported functions for each such searchable field:

```
find(Value, Field, AddressBook) ->
    case lists:keyfind(Value, Field, AddressBook) of
        #contact{fname=Fname, lname=Lname} -> {Fname, Lname};
        false -> {error, not_found}
    end.

findByPhone(Phone, AddressBook) -> find(Phone, #contact.phone, AddressBook).
findByMail(Mail, AddressBook) -> find(Mail, #contact.mail, AddressBook).
```

Comment: I did it your way but it return empty list `[]`. I call function `findByCity(City, AB)` where `City` is city string and `AB` is addressbook with stored filled records. I changed AddressBook on AB in list compr. of course.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3W04T40m thats how function looks like. And it not reutrn empty list but error because `List` is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but you'll need to show the values of your `City` and `AB` variables as well before anyone can help you. Until then, try this in an Erlang shell: `City = "Stockholm", [{C#contact.fname, C#contact.lname} || C <- [#contact{fname="Joe", lname="Armstrong", city="Stockholm"}], C#contact.city == City].` and you'll see the returned list is not empty because the `city` matches, as expected.

Comment: Here is my test code: http://pastebin.com/k97iev0u. I excluded all unnecessary functions and included some simple tests. Doesn't matter if list is empty or suppossed to be not empty it return error message like for empty list. Whats wrong there? Your shell example works so I am wondering why it don't work in my addressBook.

Comment: In your code you're adding the city to a record via `H#contact{city=[City]}`. I don't think you want the city in a list. It will work if you set it like this instead: `H#contact{city=City}`. I modified all your code to fix this and other issues and to use common Erlang coding style [here](http://pastebin.com/R2yGYcJT), hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much :). It works now just fine, thanks for advices. Why in this case assingment using list `[City]` don't work with list comprehension? Is it nested list and thats why?

Comment: It has nothing to with the list comprehension, but rather that `City` and `[City]` are two different values and so won't compare equal.